# How to make this optical illusion in 3D with Tube instead of Line?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

I made this optical illusion so that the half spheres disappear at some point and another illusion is that you may switch from perceiving spheres from convex to concave and vice versa.

How to do the same output but with `Tube`-s instead of `Line`-s and with `MaterialShading` and `Lighting`?

Lines can be replaced afterwards with `/.Line->Tube` but how to add `MaterialShading` and `Lighting`?

```
Plot3D[{Piecewise[{{Sqrt[
     2 - (x + 2)^2 - (y - 2)^2], (x + 2)^2 + (y - 2)^2 < 2}, {-Sqrt[
      2 - (x - 2)^2 - (y - 2)^2], (x - 2)^2 + (y - 2)^2 < 2}, {-Sqrt[
      2 - (x + 2)^2 - (y + 2)^2], (x + 2)^2 + (y + 2)^2 < 2}, {Sqrt[
     2 - (x - 2)^2 - (y + 2)^2], (x - 2)^2 + (y + 2)^2 < 2}}, 
   0]}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotStyle -> Transparent, Mesh -> {18, 18}, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", 
 SphericalRegion -> Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 4.2], ImageSize -> 500, 
 ImagePadding -> None, ImageMargins -> 0, 
 Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "ArcBall"}, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
 MeshStyle -> {Directive[{Opacity[0.5], Thick, Black}], 
   Directive[{Opacity[0.5], Thick, Black}]}, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 2}, 
 ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 0}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
 PlotPoints -> 200]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Define "nice and realistic."

Comment: Like when you make some 3D graphics with predefined settings and then you use `MaterialShading` and `Lighting` which makes it looking more realistic and more nice.

Comment: try `MeshStyle -> {{MaterialShading[{"Glazed", Black}],   Tube[.07]}, {MaterialShading[{"Glazed", Black}], Tube[.07]}}` and `Lighting -> "ThreePoint"`?

Comment: @kglr: It made my Mathematica frozen.

Comment: @kglr: It does not work, the tubes are ugly black. But with `MeshStyle -> {MaterialShading[{"Glazed", Black}],   Tube[.07]}` Tubes look good but they are only in `x` direction but not `y`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "13.3.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)"
> ```

```
pw[x_, y_] := Piecewise[
    {{Sqrt[2 - (x + 2)^2 - (y - 2)^2], (x + 2)^2 + (y - 2)^2 < 2}, 
     {-Sqrt[2 - (x - 2)^2 - (y - 2)^2], (x - 2)^2 + (y - 2)^2 < 2}, 
     {-Sqrt[2 - (x + 2)^2 - (y + 2)^2], (x + 2)^2 + (y + 2)^2 < 2}, 
     {Sqrt[2 - (x - 2)^2 - (y + 2)^2], (x - 2)^2 + (y + 2)^2 < 2}}, 
    0]

options = {
    AspectRatio -> 1, 
    Mesh -> {18, 18}, 
    BoundaryStyle -> None, 
    Boxed -> False, 
    PlotStyle -> None,
    Axes -> False, 
    ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", 
    SphericalRegion -> Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 4.2], 
    ImageSize -> 500, 
    ImagePadding -> None, 
    ImageMargins -> 0, 
    Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "ArcBall"}, 
    BoxRatios -> Automatic,
    ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 2}, 
    ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 0},  
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
    PlotPoints -> 200, 
    Lighting -> "ThreePoint", 
    Exclusions -> None};
```

We can use `Tube` as `MeshStyle` directive:

```
meshStyle = {MaterialShading[{"Glazed", Red}], JoinForm["Round"],   Tube[.09]};

Plot3D[pw[x, y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
  Evaluate @ options, MeshStyle -> {meshStyle, meshStyle}]
```

[image]

Comment: So the problem was `PlotStyle -> Transparent`. Try the same code replacing `PlotStyle -> None` with `PlotStyle -> Transparent` and it will freeze Mathematica. Which really it should not happen. And I consider it to be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

While I have not figured out how to use tubes with MaterialShading I found out that using `PlotStyle -> None` instead of `PlotStyle -> Transparent` and completely removing `MeshStyle -> {Directive[{Opacity[0.5], Thick, Black}]` improves the final quality of graphics considerably.

[image]